# PyQT6 QSplitter, QGridlayout with a stretch factor?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6, qgridlayout, qsplitter

Utilizing *PYQT6* I want to be able to set multiple frames on it. One of the frames needs to dynamically resize as the user increases or decreases the overall dimensions of the UI. I initially started off with a *QGridlayout*, but I couldn't find any way to scale the efficiently. So I eventually came across *QSplitter*

Using QSplitter I implemented something like this.

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QLinearGradient, QPainter
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFrame,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QSplitter,
    QWidget,
)

LIGHT_BLUE = QColor(0, 102, 153)
WHITE = QColor(255, 255, 255)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        left = QFrame(self)
        left.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        right = QFrame(self)
        right.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)

        bottom = QFrame(self)
        bottom.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)

        v_splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Orientation.Vertical)

        h_splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        h_splitter.addWidget(left)
        h_splitter.addWidget(right)
        h_splitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1)
        h_splitter.setSizes([150, 50])
        h_splitter.setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle {image: none;}")

        v_splitter.addWidget(h_splitter)
        v_splitter.addWidget(bottom)
        v_splitter.setSizes([150, 50])
        v_splitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1)
        v_splitter.setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle {image: none;}")
            
        hbox.addWidget(v_splitter)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("QtGui.QSplitter")
        # self.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event) -> None:

        painter = QPainter(self)
        grad1 = QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, int(event.rect().height() * 0.22))
        grad1.setColorAt(0.0, WHITE)
        grad1.setColorAt(1, LIGHT_BLUE)

        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), grad1)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This does exactly what I want it to do in regards to the resizing. I can even hide the handles of the *QSplitter* by setting the *styleSheet*. The top left frame scales up and down as the overall UI is resized by the user.

The Right and Bottom frames remain the same size. This is exactly what I need it to do. However, the issue that I have is that the user can still hover over the divided area, grab the handle, and resize the frames.

I've not been able to find anything related to the *QSplitter* handle that will allow me to disable the ability to resize the splitter by grabbing the handle.

This honestly just sounds like a *QGridlayout*, but with an implementation of *stretchFactor*. Which doesn't seem to exist.

How would you go about implementing this?

Comment: QGridLayout *does* have stretch factors: [`setColumnStretch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch) and [`setRowStretch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgridlayout.html#setRowStretch). Using QSplitter for this is inefficient, if you have issues setting proper size proportions in layouts, ask a question about that.